# WPF installation

Tags: wpf, web-deployment

I'm new to WPF, and created a 1st simplistic WPF application that I want it to run in a webbrowser, IE or Fox.

1 - Within the Visual Studio project, I created a /Images folder with a few .jpg files

On the WPF xaml form I have 1 image and 1 button.

When application starts, the image displays /Images/**img1.jpg**

When User clicks the button the image must display /Images/**img2.jpg**

How can I force the VS publisher **to include the Images folder?** Apparently I can't see it in the ApplicationFiles ?

2 - Though I was able to program and run this small app on my local computer, I'm getting lost when it comes to deploying to my hosting ASP where I have a Windows hosting account that runs .NET 3.5!

From Microsoft WPF website they say I shall deploy 3 files:

"The Application Executable .exe

The Deployment Manifest .xbap

The application Manifest .manifest

The .xbap file contains the information that ClickOnce uses to deploy the application and has the .xbap extension."

**But I can's see no .xbap files at all within the published stuff!!!**

Any clue  please?

Comment: If you want to run in a browser, you should be using Silverlight, not WPF.  WPF is desktop only.

Comment: @Jason - XBAP applications run in browsers! Recommending XBAP, well that's a separate issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question:

The images will be embedded in the compiled application, so you will not see the images in the application files.

Note:

1. The build action of images added to your project is 'Resource' by default - leave this as is.
2. Do not use the resources tab in the Project properties window, just drop and drag the images into the Images folder in the solution explorer.

To help answer your second question:

Did you create the project as an WPF Browser Application? 
In your .csproj file you should see the following:

```
<HostInBrowser>true</HostInBrowser>
<Install>False</Install>
<ApplicationExtension>.xbap</ApplicationExtension>
<TargetZone>Internet</TargetZone>
```

If not, just recreate the project as a WPF Browser Application and copy your files from the existing project to the new one.